# Form validation, regular expressions? Need 2 strings only

Tags: php, regex

I have a form that people must fill in. There has to be checks if the person filled in the form correctly. Now I need 2 type of checks but I have no clue how to accomplish this. I looked up regular expressions but I only get errors (deprecated??) and I am stuck on tutorials. What I need should be easy enough.

1) string may only contain letters and dots

2) string may only contain letters, dashes - and '

Who can help me?

Comment: Before looking for tutorials, look for the fantastic PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php

Comment: I did, couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// (1)
if ( preg_match('/[^\w\.\']/u', $field1) )
    ... check one failed

// (2)
if ( preg_match('/[^\w]/u', $field2) )
    ... check two failed

// (3)
if ( preg_match('/[^\d]/', $field3) )
    ... check three failed

// (4)
if ( preg_match('/[^\w\d]/u', $field4) )
    ... check four failed

// (5) emails cannot be checked a 100% but ...
if ( !preg_match('/^(?:[0-9a-z\_\-]+\.?)+\@(?:[0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/i', $field5) )
    ... check five failed
```

Comment: Thank you. Number 1 and 2 aren't workin though. 1) I need a string that only allows letters and dots. 2) I only need to allow letters, dash - and '  . 3) I need one with letters only. Can you help me with these 3?

Answer (score 1):

are you using eregi? because that function is deprecated since php 5.3.0.

look this website: http://takien.com/513/how-to-fix-function-eregi-is-deprecated-in-php-5-3-0.php

Comment: Yes in fact I did use eregi! Thanks for your comment. I'm going to check out that website.

Answer (score 0):

**1) string may only contain letters, dots and ' (NOTE: I use mysql_real_escape_string) how do I solve this?**

```
^[A-Za-z0-9.']+$
```

**2) string may only contain letters**

[Regular Expression to match only letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707591/regular-expression-to-match-only-letters)

**3) string may only contain numbers**

[Regex to match "{number}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225042/regex-to-match-number)

**4) string may only contain letters and numbers**

combine 2) and 3)

**5) check for valid email address**

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)